# Image cropping using a graphics intersect

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have an image with height and width , 230 and 200 respectively.
I need to draw the image as clipped by the graphics path I have. ie., the image should be drawn in the shape of A B C etc.,
I tried this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.texturebrush.aspx), but it did not work for me.

How can I achieve this.?

Is anything like graphics path intersect property for this?

I have the image as like [image: this] and graphics path as like [image: this]. I need to achieve that "s" shape filled with the image.

```
Brush texture = new TextureBrush(img);
if (pathtocropimage != null)
    PageGraphics.FillPath(texture, pathtocropimage);
```

Here, img is the dark image
pathtocropimage is the grpahics path which draws the "s" as in above.

Comment: Well it would be hard to guide you without you showing the current code that you have ..please paste the code that you have which is causing this problem that you are experiencing